# JUnit service class with executors return control immediately

Tags: java, junit, executorservice

I have next service class:

```
    public class JDBCServiceImpl {
      //////
      public void writeTablesColumnsToFiles(DataSource dataSource, List<Table> tableInfos) {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            for (Table table : tableInfos) {
                Runnable worker = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            writeTableColumnsToFiles(dataSource, table);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                executor.execute(worker);
            }
            executor.shutdown();
        }

        //////
        public void writeTableColumnsToFiles(DataSource dataSource, Table tableInfo) {
            //
            try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
               .....
            }
        }
}
```

I would like to test this service in JUnit class:

```
public class JDBCLoaderServiceImpl {
   @Test
    public void testExecutingOfJDBCService() {
      .....
      JDBCServiceImpl jdbcLoaderService = new JDBCServiceImpl();
      jdbcLoaderService.writeTablesColumnsToFiles(dataSource, allTables);
    }
}
```

The main problem that JUnit doesn't wait while executor complete it task (in debug mode I see that after this code `try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection())` service class return control). So how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to test `writeTableColumnsToFiles(DataSource dataSource, Table tableInfo)` and ignore method that work with threads.

But if you really want to test it you can mock `ExecutorService` and do all work in single thread.

Answer (score 0):

In general, JUnit isn't for testing multi-threaded execution.  (It's for *unit* testing... right there in the name.)

For instance, if one or even all of your worker threads were to throw exceptions and die, your JUnit test harness --- running in a completely different thread --- wouldn't notice.  Unless your test specifically asserted that no such failure had occurred, JUnit would record it as having passed, since the *test itself* hadn't thrown or propagated any exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Maybe you have any idea how to check my service? Maybe there are any others testing framework for this?

Comment: @Iurii:  Sorry, I've done very little testing of Java threads...  I just know that (unless there's some add-on or recent change) vanilla JUnit isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I add next code to `writeTablesColumnsToFiles` method:

```
try {
  executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This solve my issue.

Comment: That defeats the purpose, though.